# Node-Postgres Insert not working, key constrain error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I get an error when passing in a `record.leadProviderId` which has a value 'prov_2'.
When I hard code 'prov_2' as the argument in values: [] for my postgres query, the error disappears and my record gets inserted into my table.

I've been at this for hours, and have read lots of the docs but have no clue why this is happening.

I'm using nodejs with express and pg. Below is the query I build.

```js
    try{    
        const query = {
          text: "INSERT INTO employer (a, b, c, prov_id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4) returning *", 
          values: [record.id, record.imgLogo, record.pocFirstName, record.leadProviderId]
        }
    
        const results await db.query(query);
    }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    }

    Throws error message
        [1]   severity: 'ERROR',
        [1]   code: '23503',
        [1]   detail: 'Key (prov_id)=("prov_2") is not present in table "provider".',
        [1]   hint: undefined,
```

Yet, when I hard code the value for record.leadProviderId as 'prov_2'. I get a successful insert.

```js
const query = {
  text: "INSERT INTO employer (a, b, c, prov_id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4) returning *", 
  values: [record.id, record.imgLogo, record.pocFirstName, 'prov_2']
}
```

below is the response with all data (abbreviated code above)

```
[1] Result {
[1]   command: 'INSERT',
[1]   rowCount: 1,      
[1]   oid: 0,
[1]   rows: [
[1]     {
[1]       emp_id: 'emp-98285be5-bc8d-4643-9368-aa62d1fb5a8d',
[1]       emp_logo: 'JB.PNG-1660755365946-466707616',
[1]       emp_poc_first_name: '"John"',
[1]       emp_poc_last_name: '"Doe"',
[1]       emp_poc_phone: '"641-611-1114"',
[1]       emp_poc_email: '"email@pmail.com"',
[1]       emp_org_name: '"asdfas"',
[1]       emp_parent_name: '"dddasdf"',
[1]       emp_industry: '"SECURITY"',
[1]       emp_details: '"asdfadsf"',
[1]       emp_address: '"618 8th Ave"',
[1]       emp_req_skills: '"asdfadsf"',
[1]       emp_multi_loc: false,
[1]       prov_id: 'prov_2',
[1]       emp_status: '"true"',
[1]       emp_notes: '"testingfffff"',
[1]       emp_tags: [Array],
[1]       emp_long: 'long_placeholder',
[1]       emp_lat: 'lat_placeholder',
[1]       emp_created_date: '1660755365964',
[1]       emp_updated_date: '1660755365964'
[1]     }
[1]   ],
```

Console logging my req.body data shows the `leadProviderId` as: `[1] leadProviderId: '"prov_2"',`

At my wits end on this....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the quoted messages, it looks like the value sometimes has literal double quote marks as part of the value, and sometimes does not.  The one with the literal double quote marks failed, the one without them succeeded.

Comment: I got it jjanes. Thanks! I used the wrong regexp initially, your  comment spurred me to retry a different approach. 

record.leadProviderId.replace(/['"]+/g, '') worked.  It stripped all double quotations.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:
**[pg-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format)** package is recommended by the `node-postgres` docs for formatting, I noticed when I ran `pg4admin` the data being input was escaped SQL literals. So a value saved in column name would be `John Smith`.
When I was writing to my database it was saving as "John Smith" causing the mismatch. Below was my slow, but eventual conclusion to answer above.

This works

```
const prov_id = await db.query(`select prov_id from provider where prov_id=${record.leadProviderId}`);
const parentKey = prov_id.rows[0].prov_id

const query = {
    text: "INSERT INTO employer (a, b, c, prov_id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4) returning *", 
    values: [record.id, record.imgLogo, record.pocFirstName, parentKey ]
}
```

I feel this is grossly inefficient, as I'm calling my parent table to get the id, and then feeding it into an INSERT query..... but I don't know how to parse client incoming `data.prov_id`  to be in a readable format when I try to insert data into a table. Most likely, I don't have all the info to make a proper query, or database schema.....

UPDATE:

I had to use the `.replace()` to strip any extra double quotes.

```
record.leadProviderId.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
```

is what worked for me in the end.